# Auto coerce &String to &str

Tags: rust

I am trying to convert a list of pair of string references to Attributes. It works for `&str` or `&str` followed by `&String` (which is `Deref`ed to &str) or `String.as_ref()`. But when the first argument is of type `&String`, compiler errors out with:

`the trait std::convert::AsRef<[(&'static str, &str)]> is not implemented for [(&str, &std::string::String); 1]`

How to allow `&String` to coerce to `&str` as the first argument?

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Attributes<'a>(HashMap<&'static str, &'a str>);

impl<'a, T> From<T> for Attributes<'a>
where
    T: AsRef<[(&'static str, &'a str)]>,
{
    fn from(item: T) -> Self {
        Attributes(item.as_ref().into_iter().map(|&(k, v)| (k, v)).collect())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let fruit = "banana".to_string();
    let attr: Attributes = [("fruit", "apple"), ("new_fruit", &fruit)].into(); // This works. As it is coerced into &str because of the first one.
    let another: Attributes = [("fruit", &fruit)].into(); // Does not work as type is &String. Help! Make it work.
    let one_more: Attributes = [("fruit", fruit.as_ref())].into(); // Works
    println!("{:?}", attr);
    println!("{:?}", another);
    println!("{:?}", one_more);
}
```

[Link to Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=de04e150f7d1e1be86d14cd2dd79858d&version=stable)

Comment: You should perhaps consider implementing `FromIterator` as well, or instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is going to work using `AsRef` because the same type is free to implement both `AsRef<[(&str, &str)]>` and `AsRef<[(&str, &String)]>`, which would be ambiguous in any way that you would use `AsRef`.

You can instead directly implement `From` for those types that you want to support, such as various sizes of arrays.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Attributes<'a>(HashMap<&'static str, &'a str>);

macro_rules! array_impls {
    ($($N:expr)+) => {
        $(
            impl<'a> From<[(&'static str, &'a str); $N]> for Attributes<'a> {
                fn from(array: [(&'static str, &'a str); $N]) -> Self {
                    Attributes(array.iter().cloned().collect())
                }
            }

            impl<'a> From<[(&'static str, &'a String); $N]> for Attributes<'a> {
                fn from(array: [(&'static str, &'a String); $N]) -> Self {
                    Attributes(array.iter().map(|&(k, v)| (k, v.as_ref())).collect())
                }
            }
        )*
    }
}

array_impls! {
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
    10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
    20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
    30 31 32
}

fn main() {
    let fruit = "banana".to_string();

    // From<[(&str, &str); 2]>
    let attr: Attributes = [("fruit", "apple"), ("new_fruit", &fruit)].into();
    println!("{:?}", attr);

    // From<[(&str, &String); 1]>
    let another: Attributes = [("fruit", &fruit)].into();
    println!("{:?}", another);
}
```